# Search a string in enum and refactor required to replace 40 cases switch statement

Tags: c#

I need to refactor below method called "SetFormType". How to search a string in enum and refactor the below method.

So far I have tried like this and it throws an error.

```
      try
        {

            log.Log("sslogic Form type starts");

            FormTypeEnum valFormType = (FormTypeEnum)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(FormTypeEnum), formType.ToString());

            log.Log("sslogic 1 " + Enum.GetName(typeof(FormTypeEnum), formType.ToString()));

            log.Log("sslogic 2 " + Enum.GetName(typeof(FormTypeEnum), valFormType.ToString()));

            value.FormType = valFormType;

            log.Log("sslogic Form type " + Enum.GetName(typeof(FormTypeEnum), formType.ToString()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Log("Stephen" + ex.InnerException.ToString());
            throw new NotImplementedException("Unknown or unsupported form identifier " + Enum.GetName(typeof(FormTypeEnum), formType.ToString()));
        }
```

**Enum**

```
//
// Summary:
//     Type of form submitted
public enum FormTypeEnum
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Generic email
    GenericEmail = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Partner Access Request
    PartnerAccessRequest = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     CareersVacancySubmission
    CareersAgencyVacancySubmission = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     CareersCandidateVacancySubmission
    CareersCandidateVacancySubmission = 3,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     OemSubmitSaviDtkAccessRequest
    OemSubmitSaviDtkAccessRequest = 4,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     OemSubmitPartnerRequest
    OemSubmitPartnerRequest = 5,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     ContactSupportSubmitSample
    ContactSupportSubmitSample = 6,
    .
    .
    .
    .
    n
```

**Method need to be refactored: -**

```
    public static void SetFormType(this FormSubmission value, FormType formType)
    {
        switch (formType)
        {
            case FormType.BetaForm:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.BetaForm;
                break;
            case FormType.BetaTrial:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.BetaTrial;
                break;
            case FormType.CareersAgencyVacancySubmission:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.CareersAgencyVacancySubmission;
                break;
            case FormType.CareersCandidateVacancySubmission:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.CareersCandidateVacancySubmission;
                break;
            case FormType.ContactSupportApplicationControlRequest:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.ContactSupportApplicationControlRequest;
                break;
            case FormType.ContactSupportSubmitSample:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.ContactSupportSubmitSample;
                break;
            case FormType.WfmContactSupportSubmitSample:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.WfmContactSupportSubmitSample;
                break;
            case FormType.ContactSupportSupportQuery:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.ContactSupportSupportQuery;
                break;
            case FormType.WfmContactSupportSupportQuery:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.WfmContactSupportSupportQuery;
                break;
            case FormType.WfmContactSupportQueryNoCascadeControl:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.WfmContactSupportQueryNoCascadeControl;
                break;
            case FormType.GenericEmail:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.GenericEmail;
                break;
            case FormType.PartnerAccessRequest:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.PartnerAccessRequest;
                break;
            case FormType.OemSubmitPartnerRequest:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.OemSubmitPartnerRequest;
                break;
            case FormType.OemSubmitSaviDtkAccessRequest:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.OemSubmitSaviDtkAccessRequest;
                break;
            case FormType.WebToLead:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.WebToLead;
                break;
            case FormType.MailArchiving:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.MailArchiving;
                break;
            case FormType.EssentialFirewall:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.EssentialFirewall;
                break;
            case FormType.HomeUseFirewall:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.HomeUseFirewall;
                break;
            case FormType.CommandCenter:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.CommandCenter;
                break;
            case FormType.GenericLead:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.GenericLead;
                break;
            case FormType.GatewayBuilder:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.GatewayBuilder;
                break;
            case FormType.MspPartnerRequest:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.MspPartnerRequest;
                break;
            case FormType.Lead:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.Lead;
                break;
            case FormType.CloudTrial:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.CloudTrial;
                break;
            case FormType.FormEmail:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.FormEmail;
                break;
            case FormType.SessionRegister:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.SessionRegister;
                break;
            case FormType.SessionRequest:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.SessionRequest;
                break;
            case FormType.TrainingRegister:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.TrainingRegistration;
                break;
            case FormType.TrainingRequest:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.TrainingRequest;
                break;
            case FormType.DataCapture:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.DataCapture;
                break;
            case FormType.Questionnaire:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.Questionnaire;
                break;
            case FormType.LicensingRequest:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.LicensingRequest;
                break;
            case FormType.WebsiteReassessment:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.WebsiteReassessment;
                break;
            case FormType.WfmContactSupportApplicationControlRequest:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.WfmContactSupportApplicationControlRequest;
                break;
            case FormType.URIClassification:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.URIClassification;
                break;
            case FormType.SGNTrial:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.SGNTrial;
                break;
            case FormType.SFOSTrial:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.SFOSTrial;
                break;
            case FormType.SandstormUTM:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.SandstormUTM;
                break;
            case FormType.SophosCentral:
                value.FormType = FormTypeEnum.SophosCentral;
                break;
            default:
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Unknown or unsupported form identifier " + Enum.GetName(typeof(FormTypeEnum), formType.ToString()));
                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You are comparing a TYPE with a enumeration.  The best way is to cast both to a string.  The type you want to use the short string.  The enumeration you may need to edit the name to match the type string.

Comment: Why can you not just condense `SetFormType` to `value.FormType = formType;`

Comment: Are you refactoring this to make the code simpler/shorter? If so, you might want to consider declaring a `static Dictionary<FormType, FormTypeEnum> _lookup;` and just using that to convert.

Comment: What is `FormType`? A different enum that happens to have all these members but with different values?

Comment: What error are you getting? When are you getting it? I don't know what `FormType`, the type of `formType` is, but assuming it is an `enum` as well whose values are named exactly the same as `FormTypeEnum` then the call to `Enum.Parse` should be working. The way you're using `Enum.GetName` will thrown an `Exception`, however. The second parameter must be an `Enum` base, or an underlying type for an `Enum` like an `int`. You're passing it a `string`.

Comment: namespace Fairfax.Domain.Services.Data
{
    public enum FormType
    {
        GenericEmail,
        PartnerAccessRequest,
        CareersAgencyVacancySubmission,
        CareersCandidateVacancySubmission,
        OemSubmitSaviDtkAccessRequest,
        OemSubmitPartnerRequest,
        ContactSupportSubmitSample,
        ContactSupportApplicationControlRequest,
        ContactSupportSupportQuery,
        WfmContactSupportSupportQuery,
        WfmContactSupportQueryNoCascadeControl,
        BetaForm,  
        WebToLead,